# Need help with Ionic rewriter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

```
RewriteRule ^/main/mypage$ / [I]
RewriteRule ^/main/mypage/$ /main/general/myPage.aspx?ID=$1&gid=$2 [I]
```

Above's the ionic entry in my `.ini` file.

Now, when I write the following in my code file and run it it says "file not found". What's wrong?

```
str = str.Replace("#RESET#", "<a href='" + QAB.Con.mySite + "mypage?myID=" + ID + "&gd=" + gid + "'>Click here</a>");
```

Something's wrong with this part:-

```
"mypage?myID=" + UserID + "&gd=" + gid + "
```

Because when I type here the full name of the page, that is, `/main/general/myPage.aspx` instead of the above part then it runs all right.

How can it be fixed?

**[EDIT]
I made changes in "str" as follows. The same problem persists.**

```
"mypage/" + ID + "/" + gid + "
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the variables names or anything btw..have checked over n over..Why's no one answering..Is my ques even visible or I need to post again? :/

Comment: did my answer help or are you still having an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the end slash, e.g., change

```
RewriteRule ^/main/mypage/$ /main/general/myPage.aspx?ID=$1&gid=$2 [I]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^/main/mypage$ /main/general/myPage.aspx?ID=$1&gid=$2 [I]
```

Cheers Tigger